# LinearLayout and GestureDetector

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out, if it's possible to use `GestureDetector` for `LinearLayout` or just `ScrollEvent`?

Any Examples?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved my problem combining `Activity`'s `GestureDetector` and `OnTouchListener` for my `LinearLayout`.